# Can window.open open multiple tabs at once?

Tags: javascript

Can I open a new window but with multiple tabs?

Something like this:

```
window.open("cnn.com;foxnews.com;nyt.com");
```

Comment: Probably not. But what's wrong with calling open thrice ?

Comment: @dystroy: Think he wants to open one window with two tabs. Called `open` twice will give you two windows with one tab (apparently).

Comment: @Matt You might be right.

Comment: I need all 3 tabs to opened in a *new* window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: will the three tabs have different urls and will they pop up at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

it's Possible open multiple tabs at once the below code is useful

```
 function openMultipleTabs() {
        var w1 = window.open('http://localhost/sample/first.aspx', '1');
        var w2 = window.open('http://localhost/sample/second.aspx', '2');
        var w3 = window.open('http://localhost/sample/third.aspx', '3');
       }
```

Comment: this does work in latest chrome after allowing popups

Answer (score 3):

There's no concept of tab in standard DOM.

In fact when you ask the browser to open a window it might be a tab, depending on the browser and user settings.

So, apart writing extensions that the user will have to install, no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.There is absolutely nothing that a coder can do to open multiple tabs.No for loops can do the job.

The closest I got to a solution was--

Using `setInterval` with every interval redirecting to some page.But again this cant be occuring at a single instance.

so,the best that you can do is have a `window.open("someurl.com")` getting opened up in new tab and `window.location.href="some_other_url.com";` which will open in the same tab.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx433/)

But,there is nothing that can open multiple tabs at single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to open multiple tabs using `window.open` if you specify a different `windowName` when calling `var window = window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);`

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) state that `windowName` is:

> A DOMString specifying the name of the browsing context (window, iframe or tab) into which to load the specified resource; if the
> name doesn't indicate an existing context, a new window is created and
> is given the name specified by windowName.
>
> This name can be used as the target for the target attribute of  or
>
> elements. The name should not contain whitespace. Keep in mind
> that this will NOT be used as the window's title.