# How can I open multiple tabs in Chrome or IE - works in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, tabs, window.open

I am trying to allow the user to view multiple documents by clicking one button. I have the following, which works in Firefox, but can't get it to work in Chrome or IE:

```
`<a href ="#" class="yourlink">Click Here</a>
 ` <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('http://example.com/app/uploads/view/288/FILE_288_1476374478.pdf');
        window.open('http://example.com/app/uploads/view/288/FILE_288_14763744781.pdf');
    });
  </script>`
```

Is there any other way to get this to work on all 3 browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can window.open open multiple tabs at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887367/can-window-open-open-multiple-tabs-at-once)

Comment: Window.open(url, '_blank');

Comment: I had tried window.open(url,'_blank');, and it works in Firefox, but not Chrome or IE @bassxzero

Comment: @Fralec - the possible duplicate only allows opening url in 1 additional tab and viewing another url in same tab as request.

Comment: @s-lynch, no he just show the closest solution.

Comment: @Fralec - are you thinking that it's not possible in Chrome or IE to open more than 1 additional tab? In Chrome, if I click on 2 separate links, 2 separate tabs are open.

Comment: @s-lynch, clicking on to separate links is not the question. Did you read it?

Comment: @Fralec - yes, I did.  I am just saying that it is possible to open multiple tabs non-programmatically. I would want to simulate the clicking on multiple links programmatically, if that would do the trick.