# How to open new window with multiple tabs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to open a link in a new window that opens multiple tabs.  Currently, I am able to to open multiple tabs in the same window; this looks something like:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open('http://yahoo.com');
      window.open('http://google.com');
```

So clicking a link of class 'yourlink' will open multiple links on the same window.
For doing the same thing, but in a new normal window, I have tried using the following jquery arguments `window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings')` in the first `window.open`.  However this only makes one link open in a new window, and also in an undesirable format.

Comment: The `window` object in your code represents the current window. So whenever you use `window.open` it can only create a new tab in the current window or a fresh new window. But you cannot create a tab in the newly created window

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in javascript.
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887468)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that, by doing this :

Let's say that your current file is `index.html`.

**Step 1 :** Create a new file, say, in same folder as of `index.html`. (let's say `temp.html`).

**Step 2 :** Now in the JavaScript code `index.html`, write :

```js
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('./temp.html', '_blank', 'location=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
});
```

This will open a new window.

**Step 3 :** Just add `script` tag in `temp.html`, and write following code inside it:

```js
var links = ['http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com'];
for(let i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++){
   window.open(links[i]);
}
window.close();
```

In the array, put all the links you want to get opened.