# How to open several urls with window.open at the same time?

Tags: javascript

In my app (with alpinejs 3 ) I have texarea with several urls entered(any url on any new line)
and I try to open any url in new tab of my browser:

```
        let arr = content_textarea.split( String.fromCharCode(10) );
        let l= arr.length

        // let windowFeatures = "left=100,top=100,width=320,height=320";

        for (let i= 0; i< l; i++) {
            console.log('arr[i]::')
            console.log(arr[i])
        //  window.open(arr[i], '_blank', windowFeatures );  // Uncommenting this line did not
            window.open(arr[i], '_blank' );
            // delay(1000); // Uncommenting this line did not
            console.log('NEXT::')

        }
```

But only 1st link is opened actually. In browsers console I see output of all lines.
If there is a way to OPEN ANY url in separate browsers tab ?

I tried Google Chrome Version 100.0.4896.75 under kubuntu 20.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30883564/12057512

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let arr = content_textarea.split( String.fromCharCode(10) );
let l= arr.length

for (let i= 0; i< l; i++) {
    window.open(arr[i], i);
}
```

Comment: No that does not work for me. Only 1st url is opened